# Why is this flexbox fixed header/footer layout broken in Opera?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, opera

I have a flexbox layout with fixed header and footer and scrollable content. The header and footer have fixed hight.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  /*overflow: hidden;*//*it makes things somewhat better...*/
}
body {
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: LightGrey;
}
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: SandyBrown;
}
#header {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: LightSkyBlue;
}
#center {
  background-color: PapayaWhip;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
#footer {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: Aquamarine;
}
#menu {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: LightSalmon;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
#menu div {
  height: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: Crimson;
  position: relative;
}
#menu div span {
  display: none;
}
#menu div:hover span {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  z-index: 100 !important;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 50px;
}
#content {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: LightGreen;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="component">
  <div id="header" class="component"></div>
  <div id="center" class="component">
    <div id="menu">
      <div>o1<span>bla 1</span>
      </div>
      <div>o2<span>bla 2</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In in quam eleifend, feugiat est vitae, pretium ligula. Integer vel interdum diam, non auctor ligula. Ut vel semper justo. Fusce augue nunc, aliquam id hendrerit vitae, gravida vel metus.
        Maecenas placerat pretium gravida. Phasellus tempus facilisis felis, id ultricies magna convallis vitae. Duis posuere at quam sit amet consectetur.</p>
      <p>In lorem massa, tristique in diam at, condimentum posuere tellus. Aliquam malesuada facilisis nunc, id consectetur neque bibendum varius. Quisque consectetur turpis nec purus lobortis efficitur. Nunc ultrices et metus sed lobortis. Donec tincidunt
        mi nec neque dignissim, sit amet pretium leo eleifend. Aenean vehicula, nibh a pretium faucibus, est ligula tempor enim, quis feugiat mi orci in orci. Cras facilisis fermentum dolor in vestibulum. Aenean est lorem, fringilla sit amet velit sit
        amet, porttitor tincidunt ligula.</p>
      <p>Pellentesque a odio enim. Fusce rutrum, neque pretium placerat bibendum, lacus velit volutpat orci, sed faucibus risus purus et lacus. Suspendisse tempor urna erat, eget egestas ante iaculis eget. Cras ut tellus eu elit posuere efficitur et id magna.
        Aliquam sagittis leo eget ipsum ultricies tempus. Donec porta odio at euismod tincidunt. Ut sagittis vel urna in congue. Pellentesque viverra ante ut lacus imperdiet lobortis. Praesent placerat placerat egestas. Vivamus egestas metus id consectetur
        varius. Curabitur vel nisi vitae sapien pretium malesuada.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer" class="component"></div>
</div>
```

This works in all major browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE 10, IE 11) but in Opera there's a strange "gap" between the `center`and `footer` containers. There are actually two scroll bars instead of one. It seams to happen only when the `content` has a scroll bar.
The outer scroll bar appears to be on the `body` or the `html`. If I set `overflow: hidden` on these elements, the page still renders two scroll bars but the outer one disappears after first hovering the `menu` element. See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9vyvp5k5/1/) and play with the height of the result frame.

How can I fix this so that it works as expected in all browsers, including Opera (latest).

**Edit:**
Here are a couple of screen-shots, showing the described behavior (the orange gap on top of the footer), both while browsing with Opera:

- [Stack Overflow code snippet](http://prnt.sc/ac8ii3)
- [JSFiddle](http://prnt.sc/ac8hjz)

Comment: I don't see any gap in Opera, and there is only one scrollbar, on middle container  http://prnt.sc/ac8fe7  Same behavior as in Canary

Comment: @WolfWar please check the attached screen-shots.

Comment: on my win10 there is no gap or double scrollbars, here or on jsfiddle, I'm guessing by your SS's you are testing this on win7?

Comment: What version of Opera do you use?

Comment: tested in all three latest channel builds (stable dev and beta) stable is 35.0.2066.92

Comment: @WolfWar yes, I'm currently on Windows 7.

Comment: @KevinRestiaens the latest stable release 34.0.2036.39. But the layout was built some time ago (>6 months) and don't remember it to work.

Comment: latest stable is 35.2066.92 http://get.geo.opera.com/pub/opera/desktop/

Comment: @WolfWar strange. Opera reported it being the latest available release. Anyway, after the update everything appears to be fine.